# What's so bad about looking into the face of a wicked person?

Tags: halacha, see-sight-vision-blind, evil-resha, tractate-megillah, face

In tractate megila of the Babylonian talmud the sages say that it is forbidden to look into the face of a wicked person. What is the reason for this prohibition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the problem with looking at a wicked person? And who does it apply to?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/79052/whats-the-problem-with-looking-at-a-wicked-person-and-who-does-it-apply-to)

Comment: @WAF I closed and then regretted and reopened. You may want to reconsider reapplying your vote. My apologies. The other q is closed as too broad so this can be construed as separating out the components, so i decided to leave it alone. others may differ

Comment: Please specify where it says this. I really don't want to read the "whole Megillah". I know that *Pirkei Avot* says to distance oneself from a "bad neighbor" (which, according to some opinions, is a "lesser" form of a "wicked person".) So, if you have to stay away, I infer that you shouldn't see that person's face.

Answer (score 3):

Rav Avigdor Miller [was](https://torasavigdor.org/rav-avigdor-miller-on-the-face-of-the-rasha/) asked this same question:

> **Q:** What is the problem with looking at the face of a wicked person? [אסור
>   לאדם להסתכל בצלם דמות אדם רשע – “It is forbidden for one to gaze at
>   the face (image) of a wicked person” (Megillah 28a). ]
>
> **A:** If you look at the face of a רשע, you become a רשע. And I’ll tell
>   you why. We are influenced by people. And the face of רשע is a screen.
>   It’s a projector. And his נשמה projects its image on that screen. So
>   his רשעות is on his face.
>   You might not recognize it, you might not see it, but the רשעות is on
>   his face. And when you look at his face, it becomes stamped on your
>   נשמה. What you see is stamped on your נשמה.
>
> **1)** That’s very important. What you see will affect you. Don’t be מסתכל
>   בפני רשע. Don’t look at the face of wicked people. And don’t look at
>   people doing wrong things. As much as possible, avoid getting the
>   stamp of wrong things on your נשמה.
>
> **2)** And I want to tell you something else – another reason. Hashem doesn’t
>   like the רשעים. A רשע is busy frustrating his own purpose in life and
>   is busy ruining others as well. And Hashem is disgusted with that.
>   Now, when someone feels disgust with somebody else, if you’re really
>   disgusted by someone, then you don’t even want to look at that person.
>   And Hashem doesn’t want to look at the רשעים. And if you walk in the
>   ways of Hashem, you will also be disgusted by the רשע and his
>   behavior. You don’t even want to see him. You don’t want to look at
>   his face. And that’s why we don’t look at the face of a רשע. We are
>   training ourselves to be disgusted with those who disgust Hashem.
>
> [1](https://torasavigdor.org/rav-avigdor-miller-on-the-face-of-the-rasha/):
>   https://torasavigdor.org/rav-avigdor-miller-on-the-face-of-the-rasha/